# Composite sObject Collection call not reaching limit

Tags: rest-api, sobject, composite

The Composite API docs ([ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite_post.htm)) asserts that

> You can have up to 25 subrequests in a single call. Up to 5 of these
> subrequests can be sObject Collections or query operations, including
> Query and QueryAll requests.

However, I am a bit confused because I was not able to replicate this scenario.

I understood that I cannot send up to 25 subrequests in a single call. I already tried a request such as

```
{
    "allOrNone": true,
    "compositeRequest": [{
        method: "GET",
        url: "/services/data/v55.0/composite/sobjects/Contact?ids=SOME_ID&fields=id,name",
        referenceId: ID_1
    },
    // REPEAT STRUCTURE CHANGING ID
    {
        method: "GET",
        url: "/services/data/v55.0/composite/sobjects/Contact?ids=SOME_ID&fields=id,name",
        referenceId: ID_26
    }]
}
```

and I have below response

```
{
    "compositeResponse": [
        {
            "body": [
                {
                    "errorCode": "LIMIT_EXCEEDED",
                    "message": "The request can’t contain more than 25 operations."
                }
            ],
            "httpHeaders": {},
            "httpStatusCode": 400,
            "referenceId": null
        }
    ]
}
```

To reach the limit of 5 sObject Collections, I tried

```
{
    "allOrNone": false,
    "collateSubrequests": false,
    "compositeRequest": [
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "/services/data/v55.0/composite/sobjects/",
            "referenceId": "test1",
            "body": {
                "allOrNone": false,
                "records": [
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "type": "Contact"
                        },
                        "LastName": "John",
                        "FirstName": "John"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "type": "Contact"
                        },
                        "LastName": "John",
                        "FirstName": "John"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "type": "Contact"
                        },
                        "LastName": "John",
                        "FirstName": "John"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "type": "Contact"
                        },
                        "LastName": "John",
                        "FirstName": "John"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "type": "Contact"
                        },
                        "LastName": "John",
                        "FirstName": "John"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "type": "Contact"
                        },
                        "LastName": "John",
                        "FirstName": "John"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But the API responds with a `200 OK`. From my understanding, this requests exceeds the limitation of 5 sObject Collections.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your second request works because it has only a single subrequest (in which you create 6 Contact records) rather than 6 subrequests.

The following would fail (or at least it should) because it contains 6 separate subrequests.

```json
{
    "allOrNone": false,
    "collateSubrequests": false,
    "compositeRequest": [
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "/services/data/v55.0/composite/sobjects/",
            "referenceId": "test1",
            "body": {
                "allOrNone": false,
                "records": [
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "type": "Contact"
                        },
                        "LastName": "John",
                        "FirstName": "John"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "/services/data/v55.0/composite/sobjects/",
            "referenceId": "test2",
            "body": {
                "allOrNone": false,
                "records": [
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "type": "Contact"
                        },
                        "LastName": "John",
                        "FirstName": "John"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "/services/data/v55.0/composite/sobjects/",
            "referenceId": "test3",
            "body": {
                "allOrNone": false,
                "records": [
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "type": "Contact"
                        },
                        "LastName": "John",
                        "FirstName": "John"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "/services/data/v55.0/composite/sobjects/",
            "referenceId": "test4",
            "body": {
                "allOrNone": false,
                "records": [
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "type": "Contact"
                        },
                        "LastName": "John",
                        "FirstName": "John"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "/services/data/v55.0/composite/sobjects/",
            "referenceId": "test5",
            "body": {
                "allOrNone": false,
                "records": [
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "type": "Contact"
                        },
                        "LastName": "John",
                        "FirstName": "John"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "/services/data/v55.0/composite/sobjects/",
            "referenceId": "test6",
            "body": {
                "allOrNone": false,
                "records": [
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "type": "Contact"
                        },
                        "LastName": "John",
                        "FirstName": "John"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I still get 200 OK as a response with your example. I don't understand why this limit is not exceeded on the SF instance that I reach.